# Finding root of a tree in a directed graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a tree structure like node(1)->node(2)->node(3). I have name as an property used to retrieve a node.

Given a node say node(3), i wanna retrieve node(1).

Query tried :

MATCH (p:Node)-[:HAS*]->(c:Node) WHERE c.name = "node 3" RETURN p LIMIT 5

But, not able to get node 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will not only return "node 1", but it should at least include one path containing it. It's possible to filter the paths to only get the one traversing all the way to the root, however:

```
MATCH (c:Node {name: "node 3"})<-[:HAS*0..]-(p:Node)
// The root does not have any incoming relationship
WHERE NOT (p)<-[:HAS]-()
RETURN p
```

Note the use of the 0 length, which matches all cases, including the one where the start node *is* the root.

Fun fact: even if you have an index on Node:name, it won't be used (unless you're using Neo4j 3.1, where it seems to be fixed since 3.1 Beta2 at least) and you have to explicitly specify it.

```
MATCH (c:Node {name: "node 3"})<-[:HAS*0..]-(p:Node)
USING INDEX c:Node(name)
WHERE NOT (p)<-[:HAS]-()
RETURN p
```

Using `PROFILE` on the first query (with a numerical `id` property instead of `name`):

```
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables               | Other                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |              0 |    1 |       0 | p                       | p                    |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |              0 |    1 |       0 | anon[23], c -- p        |                      |
| |\                    +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |              1 |    0 |       3 | anon[58], anon[67] -- p | (p)<-[:HAS]-()       |
| | |                   +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| | +Argument           |              1 |    3 |       0 | p                       |                      |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +Filter               |              1 |    3 |       3 | anon[23], c, p          | p:Node               |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |              1 |    3 |       5 | anon[23], p -- c        | (c)<-[:HAS*]-(p)     |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +Filter               |              1 |    1 |       3 | c                       | c.id == {  AUTOINT0} |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+
| +NodeByLabelScan      |              3 |    3 |       4 | c                       | :Node                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+----------------------+

Total database accesses: 18
```

and on the second one:

```
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables               | Other            |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |              0 |    1 |       0 | p                       | p                |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| +AntiSemiApply        |              0 |    1 |       0 | anon[23], c -- p        |                  |
| |\                    +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| | +Expand(All)        |              1 |    0 |       3 | anon[81], anon[90] -- p | (p)<-[:HAS]-()   |
| | |                   +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| | +Argument           |              1 |    3 |       0 | p                       |                  |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| +Filter               |              1 |    3 |       3 | anon[23], c, p          | p:Node           |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| +VarLengthExpand(All) |              1 |    3 |       5 | anon[23], p -- c        | (c)<-[:HAS*]-(p) |
| |                     +----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+
| +NodeUniqueIndexSeek  |              1 |    1 |       2 | c                       | :Node(id)        |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+---------+-------------------------+------------------+

Total database accesses: 13
```

Comment: Hold up, why wouldn't name be used by an indexed lookup in the query automatically? Is there a bug affecting Neo4j 3.0.x?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I guess so (in the cost-based planner), it's not the first time I've had to add an explicit `USING INDEX` when it should have picked it (which is why I checked here).

Comment: I think I've seen an answer before mentioning the size of the label set may have something to do with how the cost planner calculates when to use an index for lookup, I'll try to find it later. It may be a case where the benefits of an index lookup may either be more expensive or may not provide any noticeable gain with the small set of nodes for the given label.

Comment: @InverseFalcon True, it could be that. However, I tried the same request with the same minimal dataset on 3.1 Beta2 and it did use the index directly, so the threshold would have changed at least. And there are less DB accesses with the index anyway.